# Javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I know this has been a topic before, but having searched I can't find an answer - maybe my question is too basic. However, i'm creating an html quiz - 5 pages with the score being taken from one page to the next, then scored at the end.

This is the code I'm trying to use but it's not working at all - my JS knowledge is very basic, so if someone could explain how this should work it would be much appreciated.

```js
var answers = "0";

function answerTotals() {

  if (document.getElementById("1A").checked = true) answers++;
  else(console.log("answer was incorrect"));
}

function showScore() {

  document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = "You Got " + answers + "/6";
  console.log("Score is displayed.");
}
```

```html
<div id="questions1">
  <h1>Question 1.</h1>
  <br>Why are there data types in JavaScript?
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" id="1A" onchange="question1()">As it helps a computer differentiate between different data.

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" id="1B" onchange="question1Wrong1()">There aren't.

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" id="1C" onchange="question1Wrong2()">To help it interact with Java.

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D" id="1D" onchange="question1Wrong3()">To allow it to complete a task.

  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="nextQuestion();answerTotals()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p onclick="hint1()">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so show the problem

Answer (score 1):

I notice in your first snippet :

```
var answers = "0";
function answerTotals() {

    if (document.getElementById("1A").checked = true) answers++;
    else(console.log("answer was incorrect"));
}
```

Here, in the if condition, you have used a single equal to. So, here, it is setting the value of the variable document.getElementById("1A").checked to the boolean 'true'.

You want to do :

```
if ( document.getElementById("1A").checked == true )
```

or just

```
if ( document.getElementById("1A").checked )
```

Also, the else condition you have shown uses curved brackets. Although this specific example will work with

```
else(console.log("answer was incorrect"));
```

It is incorrect and can cause confusion later. The correct way is :

```
    else console.log("answer was incorrect");
```

or

```
    else { console.log("answer was incorrect"); }
```